# Tailwind component always loads elements in OS theme, despite setting darkMode to class in tailwind.config.js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I have a dashboard where my Javascript UI library components work fine with dark/light mode, but the Navbar will ignore the dark: selector and just use the default theme set in the OS.

I thought this line `darkMode: 'class'` in tailwind.config.js make elements use their dark: selector when the dark class is added to , instead of using the system's default theme from `prefers-color-scheme`

[However in this video you can see my navbar uses prefers-color-scheme, despite darkMode being set to class?](https://imgur.com/a/9IIbT2A)

here is my navbar, as you can see the Disclosure has `bg-white and dark:bg-slate-900`

But in the video clip above the navbar only uses bg-slate-900 because the OS system is in dark mode. (changed to bg-white when I changed to windows light mode).

```
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Disclosure, Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { MagnifyingGlassIcon } from '@heroicons/react/20/solid'
import { Bars3Icon, BellIcon, XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
import { UserProfile } from "@/components/dashboard/user-profile"


export function DashboardNavbar() {
  return (
    <Disclosure as="nav" className="shadow-lg bg-white dark:bg-slate-900">
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-2 sm:px-4 lg:px-8  ">
            <div className="flex h-16 justify-between">
              <div className="flex px-2 lg:px-0">
                <div className="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img
                      className="h-13 w-auto"
                      src="https://notiongadgets.com/notionpaws.svg"
                      alt="Your Company"
                    />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div className="hidden lg:ml-6 lg:flex lg:space-x-8">
                  {/* Current: "border-indigo-500 text-gray-900", Default: "border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700" */}
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="inline-flex items-center border-b-2 border-yellow-500 px-1 pt-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
                  >
                    Your Sites
                  </a>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="inline-flex items-center border-b-2 border-transparent px-1 pt-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 dark:hover:theme-color hover:text-gray-700"
                  >
                    Help Docs
                  </a>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="inline-flex items-center border-b-2 border-transparent px-1 pt-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700"
                  >
                    Pricing
                  </a>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="inline-flex items-center border-b-2 border-transparent px-1 pt-1 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-700"
                  >
                    Calendar
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="flex items-center lg:hidden">
                {/* Mobile menu button */}
                <Disclosure.Button className="relative inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
                  <span className="absolute -inset-0.5" />
                  <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                  {open ? (
                    <XMarkIcon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                  ) : (
                    <Bars3Icon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                  )}
                </Disclosure.Button>
              </div>
              <div className="hidden lg:ml-4 lg:flex lg:items-center">
                <button type="button" className="mr-5 relative flex-shrink-0 rounded-full bg-white p-1 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2">
                  <span className="absolute -inset-1.5" />
                  <span className="sr-only">View notifications</span>
                  <BellIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                </button>

                <UserProfile></UserProfile>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <Disclosure.Panel className="lg:hidden">
            <div className="space-y-1 pb-3 pt-2">
              {/* Current: "bg-indigo-50 border-indigo-500 text-indigo-700", Default: "border-transparent text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:border-gray-300 hover:text-gray-800" */}
              <Disclosure.Button
                as="a"
                href="#"
                className="block border-l-4 border-yellow-500 bg-indigo-50 py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-base font-medium text-indigo-700"
              >
                Dashboard
              </Disclosure.Button>
              <Disclosure.Button
                as="a"
                href="#"
                className="block border-l-4 border-transparent py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-base font-medium text-gray-600 hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-800"
              >
                Team
              </Disclosure.Button>
              <Disclosure.Button
                as="a"
                href="#"
                className="block border-l-4 border-transparent py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-base font-medium text-gray-600 hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-800"
              >
                Projects
              </Disclosure.Button>
              <Disclosure.Button
                as="a"
                href="#"
                className="block border-l-4 border-transparent py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-base font-medium text-gray-600 hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-800"
              >
                Calendar
              </Disclosure.Button>
            </div>
            <div className="border-t border-gray-200 pb-3 pt-4">
              <div className="flex items-center px-4">
                <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                  <img
                    className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
                    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="ml-3">
                  <div className="text-base font-medium text-gray-800">Tom Cook</div>
                  <div className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">tom@example.com</div>
                </div>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="relative ml-auto flex-shrink-0 rounded-full bg-white p-1 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2"
                >
                  <span className="absolute -inset-1.5" />
                  <span className="sr-only">View notifications</span>
                  <BellIcon className="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="mt-3 space-y-1">
                <Disclosure.Button
                  as="a"
                  href="#"
                  className="block px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-800"
                >
                  Your Profile
                </Disclosure.Button>
                <Disclosure.Button
                  as="a"
                  href="#"
                  className="block px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-800"
                >
                  Settings
                </Disclosure.Button>
                <Disclosure.Button
                  as="a"
                  href="#"
                  className="block px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-800"
                >
                  Sign out
                </Disclosure.Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Disclosure.Panel>
        </>
      )}
    </Disclosure>
  )
}
```

and my tailwind.config.js file

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const { fontFamily } = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme")
import { library, config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
config.autoAddCss = false

module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: { 
        sans: ["var(--font-sans)", ...fontFamily.sans]
      },
      colors: {
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
}
```

So could someone point me in the right direction and make sense of this mess?

Comment: Are you setting the class to dark on the html tag. `<html class="dark">`. See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#supporting-system-preference-and-manual-selection

Comment: Nope, it's because I was using the Tailwind CDN, https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6462#discussioncomment-1812656

Spent forever wondering why it wasn't working lol and it's cause their CDN is fucked up